# Download .mp3 with VideoLibrary 3.0.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wan't to download Music from YouTube with VideoLibary 3.0.1 but i can't find anything on the Internet. How to do that?

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure it's allowed to download videos or audio from youtube. Take a look at the terms of service for the VideoLibrary on whether they allow that at all.

Comment: @peterpie It's not illegal to download Youtube videos, but you sure should not distribute it to other people/platforms afterwards.

Comment: There's a sample on how to download a video on [the project's repo](https://github.com/omansak/libvideo), which also has a [documentation page](https://github.com/omansak/libvideo/blob/master/docs/README.md)